# Update timestamp of directory reference from other directory?

Tags: linux

I am linux a linux newbie. I like to know what command can i use to update timestamp of directory reference from other directory ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.  Do you mean: 1) modify the timestamp of directory B to be equal to directory A; or 2) when directory A is modified and its timestamp is updated by the OS, also make directory B's timestamp get updated.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not very clear -- what do you mean by "directory reference", and what do you mean by "update [one timestamp] _from_ [another]"? Do you want to set the timestamp of a directory to the same timestamp that another directory has?

Answer (score 3):

```
touch -r other_directory directory_to_change
```